How do I load and read file information using NetLogo Web using the extensions 'import-a' & 'fetch'
I understand that 'NetLogo Web' does not support file-read and therefore a work around needs to be done using the extensions [import-a fetch].
In the 'NetLogo Desktop' version I was using "file-read' to import attribute data to 100 agents, for example,
    file-open "file.txt"
      while [n <= members] [
        create-people members [
          set num file-read
          set CP file-read
          set KB file-read
;; more set attributes using file-read 
        ]
;;other commands ....            
          ]

How would I do this using the fetch command. I can read the file using fetch, but I don't know how to read or load the information to the agents.
Thank you.
I tried using the following example, but I'm stuck at how to change my code to make this work.
extensions [import-a fetch]
    to test
      fetch:user-file-async [text -> show text]
      user-file-async
    end


You didn't give any sample data, but from your example I came up with something like this:
file.txt:
10 "gggg" false
18 "gfgg" true
12 "fsfg" false
14 "ffff" false
8 "eeee" false

In this case I would use the CSV extension's csv:from-string primitive, which is available on NetLogo Web, to split the string you read into a list of values.  Then you can create the turtles from those values one at a time.
extensions [ csv fetch ]

turtles-own [ number code flag ]

to setup
  let file-name "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/LaCuneta/dbc4acb709fc4294f62fe5c4665e2b6d/raw/582ffd51f6065b8229dc4a40acd981c6653aaeeb/file.txt"
  fetch:url-async file-name [ data ->
    let rows (csv:from-string data " ")
    show rows ; prints: [[10 "gggg" false] [18 "gfgg" true] [12 "fsfg" false] [14 "ffff" false] [8 "eeee" false]]
    setup-turtles rows
  ]
end

to setup-turtles [rows]
  foreach rows [ row -> 
    create-turtles 1 [
      set number item 0 row
      set code item 1 row
      set flag item 2 row
    ]
  ]
  show [(list number code flag)] of one-of turtles ; [10 "gggg" false]
end

You can try it out here, just run setup in the command center.

extensions [ csv fetch ]
turtles-own [ num CPm OnOff KB Lm Po Pl Pr Cwb S A C AA SA CoT VA Is Le]
 to setup 
 let file-name "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rfligg/175b954580eaf95e352ee37f0ce31a6f/raw/c243fe5dcf43a783fe48fc5b02ce454b1bb0dbaf/gistfile1.txt"
 fetch:url-async file-name [ data ->
    let rows (csv:from-string data " ")
    show rows 
setup-turtles rows
]
end

to setup-turtles [rows]
foreach rows [ row -> 
create-turtles 1 [
  set num item 0 row
  set CPm item 1 row
  set OnOff item 2 row
  set KB item 3 row
  set Lm item 4 row
  set Po item 5 row
  set Pl item 6 row
  set Pr item 7 row
  set Cwb item 8 row
  set S item 9 row
  set A item 10 row
  set C item 10 row
  set AA item 12 row
  set SA item 13 row
  set CoT item 14 row
  set VA item 15 row
  set Is item 16 row
  set Le item 17 row 
   ]  
]
 show [(list num CPm OnOff KB Lm Po Pl Pr Cwb S A C AA SA CoT VA Is Le)] of one-of turtles 
end


I tried using my data and set it up similar to what you did. There's an issue with reading the data from 'gist.githubusercontent....'. I think this method will work once I can read the data properly.
